# Excel - truncate entries after given word

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have links in Excel

for example -
`http://img.fkcdn.com/image/voltage-stabilizer/h/c/7/arctic-iavs-led-60-iavs-60-original-imae82pgak9mbbtf.jpeg;http://img.fkcdn.com/image/voltage-stabilizer/h/c/7/arctic-iavs-led-60-iavs-60-200x200-`

I need to truncate each entry, after the word `.jpeg`

so that, e.g.

`http://img.fkcdn.com/image/voltage-stabilizer/h/c/7/arctic-iavs-led-60-iavs-60-original-imae82pgak9mbbtf.jpeg;http://img.fkcdn.com/image/voltage-stabilizer/h/c/7/arctic-iavs-led-60-iavs-60-200x200-`

becomes

`http://img.fkcdn.com/image/voltage-stabilizer/h/c/7/arctic-iavs-led-60-iavs-60-original-imae82pgak9mbbtf.jpeg`

how can I achieve this?
I have more than 10000 links to do.

Answer (score 3):

In your question you asked

> `http://img.fkcdn.com/image/voltage-stabilizer/h/c/7/arctic-iavs-led-60-iavs-60-original-imae82pgak9mbbtf.jpeg;http://img.fkcdn.com/image/voltage-stabilizer/h/c/7/arctic-iavs-led-60-iavs-60-200x200-`
>
> becomes
>
> `http://img.fkcdn.com/image/voltage-stabilizer/h/c/7/arctic-iavs-led-60-iavs-60-original-imae82pgak9mbbtf.jpeg`

This means that you're only after the first occurance of each image.

You also are possibly thinking about the task in the wrong way - you're thinking how to truncate, where as maybe you'd have more luck if you thought about how to split, or find based upon a certain character. In this case, we can use `;`

As such

If you had the string in A1, then in B1 you would type

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1) - 1)
```

[image]

If you want to keep it all, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316094/split-a-string-cell-in-excel-without-vba-e-g-for-array-formula

Comment: Nice one. It may have been my re-interpretation of the original question wording that defined it as 'truncate'. The original wasn't really clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this quickly is use the built-in "Text to Columns".

- Select your cell(s), go to the Data Tab, then click "Text to Columns".
- Then choose "Delimited", and use a semicolon as the delimiter.
- You
  can click "Next" to set a destination for the data, or just "Finish"
  and it'll put the data in the current cell, and then to the cells
  next to it.

[image]